# Can't get opencv working with a gtk backend on my mac

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib, gtk, virtualenv

I am trying to do some human pose estimation with a cool library that can be found here:

https://github.com/DeNA/Chainer_Realtime_Multi-Person_Pose_Estimation

I have it working on still images using the tkagg backend, set via the following lines:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('tkagg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Unfortunately, to do the live webcam tracking it seems tkagg will not work. When I run the code to do live web cam tracking i get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 583
```

This seems to be telling me to use the GTK backend, which makes sense as that is what the original repo said to use. The issue is when i change the matplotlib.use line to GTK like so:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('GTK')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

This gives an error with the following trace:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mark/Downloads/myenv3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 14, in 
    import gobject
ImportError: No module named 'gobject'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "camera_pose_demo.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pose_detector import PoseDetector, draw_person_pose
File "/Users/mark/Downloads/Chainer_Realtime_Multi-Person_Pose_Estimation-master/pose_detector.py", line 8, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "/Users/mark/Downloads/myenv3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 116, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
File "/Users/mark/Downloads/myenv3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 60, in pylab_setup
    [backend_name], 0)
File "/Users/mark/Downloads/myenv3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 18, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.")
ImportError: Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.
```

This is obviously saying my program can't find the GTK backend. I have installed it via brew, but I have read of other people having this problem too - just withouth a clear answer. It seems as though I need to find GTK on my machine and explicitly tell my python program/virtualenv where that is, although i am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install [PyGTK](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyGTK) (python wrapper for GTK) which in turn require [pygobject](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pygobject/) (python wrapper for GObject).

PyGTK seems to be rather old (2011 year), I am not sure it works with Python 3.

Comment: So I need to install pygtk and pygobject and then it should work provided pyGTK is compatible with python 3?

Comment: I think so. May be there will be other required libraries — install them one by one.